# Ruby storing array into csv result in output with extra ""

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv

I have a script that is scrapping a website, generates a csv file and is storing raw data into this csv. Everything works well except when I am trying to store an array into the csv file :

```
tarif_jeune = []
tarif_adulte =[]
              html_doc.search("td table table table tr").each do |tr|
                unless (tr.css("td:nth-child(11)").text.squish == "") || (tr.css("td:nth-child(11)").text.squish.size > 5) || (tr.css("td:nth-child(11)").text.squish ==  "0,00")
                  tarif_adulte << tr.css("td:nth-child(11)").text.squish
                end
                unless (tr.css("td:nth-child(12)").text.squish == "") || (tr.css("td:nth-child(12)").text.squish.size > 5) || (tr.css("td:nth-child(12)").text.squish ==  "0,00")
                  tarif_jeune << tr.css("td:nth-child(12)").text.squish
                end
              end
```

then inserting `tarif_jeune` and `tarif_adulte` into csv file :

```
 csv << ["true", tr.css("td:nth-child(10)").text.squish, tr.css("td:nth-child(11)").text.squish, tr.css("td:nth-child(11)").text.squish, tr.css("td:nth-child(12)").text.squish, tr.css("td:nth-child(13)").text.squish, tr.css("td:nth-child(14)").text.squish, tr.css("td:nth-child(15)").text.squish,  tr.css("td:nth-child(1) a").attr("href").value, tarif_jeune.uniq, tarif_adulte.uniq, cat.uniq, address]
```

cat, tarif_jeune, tarif_adulte are all arrays. I would expect them to look like this in my csv ["poo", "faa", "foo"] but the outpout is quite different: "" are inserted everywhere and I get something like this :

```
tarif_jeune, tarif_adulte, cat
"[""15,00""]","[""20,00""]","[""Simple Messieurs 45"", ""Simple Dames Senior"", ""Simple Messieurs Senior""]"
```

Can someone explain where those extra "" come from and how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

The double quote `"` character is the default `:quote_char` in [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class.

So, if you try to write a string that comprises of double quote characters, they will be escaped by CSV class and will be written as `""` to the file.

In your case, you are writing an array of strings to CSV. When `Array#to_s` is called on a array of strings, the output will be a String that looks somewhat like below:

```
ary = ["a", "b", "c"]
puts "#{ary}"
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

The double quotes in string representation of array will be escaped by CSV class, and the above `ary` will appear as `"[""a"", ""b"", ""c""]"` in csv file.

To solve this issue, look at why you need to store the output `Array#to_s` in CSV.  You most likely want to do `ary.join(" ")` or equivalent and then write to file.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly valid csv.

Assuming you want your data to look like this (as you say in `["poo", "faa", "foo"]`):

```
tarif_jeune, tarif_adulte, cat
["15,00"],["20,00"],["Simple Messieurs 45", "Simple Dames Senior", "Simple Messieurs Senior"]
```

Here, inside the fields, there is a comma, which is also your field seperator. Therefore the fields have to be surrounded with quotes. And because your fields also contain quotes inside, those quotes need to be escaped with another quote:

```
tarif_jeune, tarif_adulte, cat
"[""15,00""]","[""20,00""]","[""Simple Messieurs 45"", ""Simple Dames Senior"", ""Simple Messieurs Senior""]"
```

Any decent csv parser should be able to handle those extra quotes. In fact, without them, your csv would be malformed.